# jquery .load not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Although the code below is working fine for me in all browsers, I'm getting some reports that the .load isn't doing what it should in IE.

I tested IE6-IE8 and it works fine for me. The `.load` is bring in the WordPress section of the site into the page and then the `click` function loads the new page within the same section of the page. Also this page where the code sits on is at the root level (`siteexample.com/new.html`) and then the WordPress is at `siteexample.com/wordpress`.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow, .slideshow2').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });

    $('.copy-body').load('/wordpress/', function() {
        $('.spinner').fadeOut();

        function rerun(){
           $('.copy-body a').click(function(){
               url = $(this).attr('href');
               scroll(0,430);

               $('.copy-body').load(url, function() {
                   $('.copy-body').
                       append('<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>');
                   rerun();
               });

               return false;
           });
        }

        $('.copy-body').append('<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>');
        rerun();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `$.cycle()` a custom plugin?

Comment: so you say it doesn't work in IE, but it does work in IE6-8?? By a process of elimination, I guess you mean it doesn't work specifically in IE9, but I wish you had been more specific.

Comment: You need to say exactly why it doesn't work in IE and which version of IE (assuming it's 9).

Comment: cycle is jquery cycle. that is a widely used plugin. i checked ie 6-8 and didn't see any issues. the person reporting this issue is using ie8. i'm gusiness it could be some security setting on their computer which is preventing the page from fully loading.

Comment: also i'm using jquery version 1.7.2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with load function, use the $.ajax function instead of load.

I have used $.ajax function in lot of applications and i do not have any browser compatibility issues with it. Make sure you change the dataType to html in the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wordpress/',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(html) {
        ... rest of your code that should be added into the load function.
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.